# Как с помощью Java резать mp3 файлы?

Tags: java

Мне нужно с помощью Java резать и клеить mp3 файлы. Подскажите, как это можно сделать и если не сложно, покажите любой пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос не очень простой. Ввиду того, что библиотек для Java, позволяющих это сделать, я не знаю, попробую оценить, как это можно реализовать самостоятельно.

Есть два основных варианта, отличающиеся по возможностям, по затратам ресурсов, времени, достоинствам и недостаткам:

Вариант 1: Программно декодировать mp3 в обычный звуковой поток, привести к одному формату (частоте дискретизации, количество битов на отсчёт и прочее), разрезать или склеить их и снова сжать в новый mp3.

Плюсы:

- Более точно (в плане времени) можно разрезать звук.
- Практически никаких сложностей с разными форматами исходных mp3.

Минусы:

- Ресурсозатратно. Кодирование и декодирование mp3 требует времени, процессора и памяти. Конечно, не очень уж и большого (раз это можно программно реализовать даже на ARM7 с их частотами до 100 МГц), но всё же.
- Необходимо найти или переписать библиотеку программного кодирования и декодирования mp3 в памяти. (Исходники в интернете на некоторых языках точно есть)

Вариант 2: т.к. mp3-файл внутри делится на более-менее независимые фреймы, можно их комбинировать без всякой перекодировки.

Плюсы:

- Это можно сделать более-менее быстро, т.к. декодировать и кодировать не требуется.
- Фреймы не очень велики и точность обрезки по ним достаточно высока.

Минусы:

- На выходе, в основном, будут vbr (с переменным битрейтом и частотой дискретизации).
- Я не знаю, как проигрыватель будет относится к фреймам с разным числом битов на отсчёт ^^"

Но в любом случае, нужно всё же разобраться в формате mp3 (особенно vbr - ввиду того, что в общем случае случайно mp3 файлы имеют разные параметры звука) для таких операций.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Буду думать как это реализовать

Comment: Копайте в сторону JLayer - это хороший mp3-декодер. С его помощью вы по крайней мере сможете реализовать второй подход.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы мне очень помогли

Answer (score 2):

Сделал 2-й метод:

```
public class Cutter {
    public Cutter(FileInputStream in, int start, int len) throws IOException, BitstreamException, DecoderException
    {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("tmp.mp3");
        Decoder decode = new Decoder();
        Bitstream bStream = new Bitstream(in);
        Header head = bStream.readFrame();
        decode.decodeFrame(head, bStream);
        try{
            byte[] arr1 = new byte[bStream.getRawID3v2().available()];
            bStream.getRawID3v2().read(arr1);
            output.write(arr1);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException ex) {}
        //time in MS
        int timeMS = (len + 1) * 1000;
        //Number of frames for cut
        int numberOfFrames = timeMS / (int)head.ms_per_frame();
        //number of bytes
        int numberOfBytesToCut = numberOfFrames  * head.framesize;
        //number bytes to skip
        int numberBytesToSkip = ((start + 1) * 1000) / (int)head.ms_per_frame() * head.framesize;
        byte[] arr = new byte[in.available()];
        in.skip(numberBytesToSkip);
        in.read(arr);
        output.write(arr, 0, numberOfBytesToCut);
        output.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов работы с mp3 файлами в java: 
а) JMF 
Проблемы: после 2002 года JMF не поддерживает формат mp3. 
б) JLayer 
в) Lame

В библиотеках куча методов по работе с mp3, в интернете множество примеров